# Camel Bindy - split() not working

Tags: csv, apache-camel, bindy

I am using Bindy with Camel to process a CSV file.

The following code, get a list of beans unmarshalled from the csv is running fine.

```
 from("ftp://blabla.com:21/InPut?password=bla&move=done&sortBy=file:name")
.unmarshal(bindy)
.process(new Processor() {
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    Message in = exchange.getIn();
                    Map<String, Object> modelMap = (Map<String, Object>) in.getBody();
                    System.out.println(modelMap.size());
                    int i = 0;
                }
            });
```

But when I am trying this:

```
from("ftp://blabla.com/InPut?password=bla&move=done&sortBy=file:name")
.unmarshal(bindy)
.split(body())
.process(new Processor() {
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    Message in = exchange.getIn();
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) in.getBody();
                    System.out.println(list.size());
                    int i = 0;
                }
            });
```

The answer of the split is empty, and there is nothing to process.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Thanks and regards

Gilles

**** SOLUTION *****
Thank you for your feedbacks. If case 1 works well and let me get a list of maps, for case 2 I had to process it line by line first, then unmarshall. In this case the body contains the POJO.

This code works:

```
 .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
 .unmarshal(bindy)
 .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    Message in = exchange.getIn();
                    Employee emp = (Employee) in.getBody();
                    System.out.println(emp);

                }
            });
```

Thank you for your help

Gilles

Comment: Do you think you using an ArrayList of HashMap  and casting the body maybe resulting in this miss?

Comment: I don't even enter the process method because the result is empty. So no casting so far

Comment: Try tokenizing the message before splitting. `.split(body().tokenize(','))` Also note that `split` used to be `splitter` in earlier versions of Camel

Comment: Thanks. I will try but after unmarshalli g the body must now contain a list of  Hahmaps. This is what I get when I don't split. So tokenizing at this time might be too late

Comment: Are you trying to get your Processor to handle an ArrayList of size 1, containing a HashMap of size 1?

Comment: Oluwafemi thank you for having pointed me to the right direction. I have added the solution at the end of my question

Comment: @Gilles Please post the solution as an answer, and then accept it. This way it may help other users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedbacks. If case 1 works well and let me get a list of maps, for case 2 I had to process it line by line first, then unmarshall. In this case the body contains the POJO.

This code works:

```
 .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
 .unmarshal(bindy)
 .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    Message in = exchange.getIn();
                    Employee emp = (Employee) in.getBody();
                    System.out.println(emp);

                }
            });
```

Thank you for your help